# How to transfer object using TCP socket between Android and QT?

Tags: android, qt, sockets

I am a newbie in QT programming. Now I have one project which will transfer data from Android phone to a local computer with QT socket server running. My problem is I know how to serialize an object and send it out from the Android phone, but I do not know how to receive it at the QT end. Any help would be great for me, thanks!

part of the codes are listed below:
Android code:

```
public void SendDataToNetwork(Infor std_infor) throws IOException { //You run this from the main thread.

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
oos.writeObject(std_infor);
oos.close();
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
try {
if (nsocket.isConnected()) {
nos.write(bytes);
} else {
Log.i("AsyncTask", "SendDataToNetwork: Cannot send message. Socket is closed");
}
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.i("AsyncTask", "SendDataToNetwork: Message send failed. Caught an exception");
}
}
}
```

the std_infor is an object which has four strings variables in it.

the Qt server:

```
void MainWindow::startRead()
{
char* rec = new char[client->readBufferSize()];
qDebug()<<client->readBufferSize();
QByteArray data = client->readAll();
qDebug()<<data;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to use something like JSON or XML to serialize and deserialize your object; the chances of it working on a byte-level or slim.

Answer (score 1):

I have done the same thing in my project which transfer objects between Qt application and Browser Extensions ( Firefox and Chrome Extensions ). Here is how the system works:

At Qt End: I use an open source project called [QHttpServer](https://github.com/nikhilm/qhttpserver) to implement a Http Server and listen to a predefined port. You can also check [A simple HTTP Server](http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtservice/qtservice-example-server.html) to see how QTcpServer works before getting down to the real job.

At the Extensions I use XmlHttpRequest to send and receive messages to that predefined port ( you should encrypt/decrypt the messages for security ). XHR is simple, and AFAIK Android also supports it.

Also, I suggest using JSON to serialize/deserialize your objects.

If you need more detail you can google "Qt Http Server".

Answer (score 0):

First of all do not use try and other exception handlers in combination with Qt.

I'm not sure what you want to do but you are probably searching for something like [QDataStream](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qdatastream.html). In combination with a [QByteArray](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qbytearray.html) you can create a data package which you can send to you client or server.

Sender:

```
QByteArray buffer;
QDataStream out(&buffer);
out << someData << someMoreData;
```

Receiver:

```
QByteArray buffer;
QDataStream in(&buffer);
in >> someData >> someMoreData;
```